# Deleted users in Openfire are not reflected in clients

Tags: user-management, xmpp, openfire

we do use Openfire as our jabber/xmpp-server. The users are added, an put into groups, which works fine, as the clients get a list of all users and appropiate users.

But when deleting a user, this change isn't reflected in the clients. The old users remain as offline contacts in the groups forever, which is really anonying to some users.

Are there any known solutions to this?
Regards

Comment: Do the deleted users persist even through a reconnect of the client (which is needed) and a restart of the OpenFire service (or just a clearing of the caches from the Cache Summary page)?

Comment: Yes and yes. Even after restarting the openfire server/clients the user remain in the clients user-list. Clearing the caches helped neither.

Comment: Huh.  Do they still show up in the `Users` tab of OpenFire?

Comment: Nope, they are deleted, and don't show up in the users list nor the groups, they were associated with.

Comment: From where you deleted those users ?? from openfire dashboard or from mysql database ?